# How to start and reset angular timer from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-timer

I want to start timer when user click on `recordLogs` method and reset timer when user click on `stopLogs` method. According to angular-timer documentation we can use `timer-stop` and `timer-clear` method to achieve these task but i am getting error `start` and `clear` undefined on timer when i invoked them from controller. Any idea ?

main.html

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
           <timer interval="1000">{{hours}} hour{{hoursS}}, {{minutes}} minute{{minutesS}}, {{seconds}} second{{secondsS}}.</timer>
 </div>
```

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.stopLogs = function() {
    $scope.timer-clear();

};

$scope.recordLogs = function() {
    $scope.timer-start();
}
```

Comment: You could at least open console and read the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out examples from here :  https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#/angularjs-single-timer-source

Comment: Thanks for sharing example, I got it we have to  $broadcast events start and clear. Thanks again!